# Trigger jenkins after code is deployed in server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How do I run my batch file once the code is deployed in IBM Websphere[Was Server] using Jenkins ? Is there any plugin available in Jenkins to observe the Changes made in the server ?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post build step to build another project only if the build is stable which is running that batch.

**EDIT**

Just add pa Post-Build Action to your deployment job to trigger another job containing your batch file. ( You most likely want the first option Triggers only if build is stable ) from below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wald. The scenario is, IBM Websphere is installed in a 'Was Server' and whenever there is a code deployment in server I want some triggering to the Jenkins so that I can run a batch file in my local machine.